# Why does fread read URLs ok on Linux but not on Windows (prior to 1.9.3)?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to read in a csv from the net.  When I run

```
library(data.table)
rawfile<-fread("http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/genoutages/20140116_genout.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,skip=2)
rawfile
```

I get

```
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: File Posted on 16-Jan-2014 04:00,V2
```

But if I download the file to my computer first and then do

```
rawfile<-fread("c:\\temp\\20140116_genout.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,skip=2)
rawfile
```

then I get the output that I expect.

I know this is easy to work around by I just wanted to see if this was a bug or if there was some nuance that was going over my head.

Comment: Quite simply, `fread` memory maps the file and you can't memory map a URL. Though `fread` could throw a warning and attempt to download the file to a temporary location, and then read it from there.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: actually, the first example works fine for me, I get 91 rows (R 3.0.2, Fedora 18)

Comment: @nico I'm using Win7 R 3.0.1 and data.table 1.8.10

Comment: @Dean MacGregor: I am using `data.table` 1.8.10 too, maybe the issue is with the OS? However note that there are major warnings in `?fread` about the function being under development and not intended for production use yet.

Comment: @nico: I just looked at the source, and it works for you because `fread` downloads the URL to a tempfile and reads that. Doesn't work for me on Windows either.

Comment: neither option works for me on windows - looks like a `skip` bug to me

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Now fixed. R's `download.file()` adds extra `\r` to make `\r\r\n` line endings on Windows-only text mode. Avoided by adding `mode='wb'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** Sep 2014 : Now fixed in v1.9.3

> URLs now work on Windows. R's `download.file()` converts `\r\n` to `\r\r\n` on Windows. Now avoided by downloading in binary mode. Thanks to Steve Miller and Dean MacGregor for reporting, [#492](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/492).

---

Thanks for reporting. It worked fine for me when I tried just now on Linux.  See output below.

`?fread` confirms that URLs are supported: "A filename input is passed through path.expand for convenience and may be a URL starting http:// or file://."

Given the comments, seems like a Windows only problem then. Have raised a bug here :
[#5288 fread reads URLs on Linux but not Windows?](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=975&func=detail&aid=5288)

Here's the output from it working on Linux :

> fread("http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/genoutages/20140116_genout.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,skip=2)
>       trying URL 'http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/genoutages/20140116_genout.csv'
>       Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 2767 bytes
>       opened URL
>       ==================================================
>       downloaded 2767 bytes

```
         Date Forecasted Generation Outage Western Region Other Regions
 1: 1/17/2014                         1543            374          1169
 2: 1/18/2014                         1520            374          1146
 3: 1/19/2014                         1520            374          1146
 4: 1/20/2014                         1520            374          1146
 5: 1/21/2014                         1520            374          1146
 6: 1/22/2014                         1520            374          1146
 7: 1/23/2014                         1506            374          1132
 .. snip
```